# How to clear the contents of a NSTableView and again reload the data on clicking of a button in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview

I have a NSTableView which I am populating using a pList. I have a clear Button to clear the contents of the Table.

The code is as below

```
 var dataArray: NSMutableArray = [];

    @IBAction func clearButton(sender: AnyObject) {        
        dataArray.removeAllObjects()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Now this is working fine. But I am not able to reload the data on another Button click. The data is getting cleared and not getting loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When the function is called you can check the length of dataarray and accordingly reload the table data.

```
@IBAction func clearButton(sender: AnyObject) {  
          if dataArray.count>0 {
            dataArray.removeAllObjects()
            tableView.reloadData()
          }
          else{
                // Code to insert element into dataArray
            tableView.reloadData()
          }
     }
```

Comment: Yes I have added, it is coming from a pList. and I have got another Button called Reload which should reload the data but once I hit the clear Button, it is not getting reloaded.

Comment: If you click Reload button dataArray is getting loaded and as the count is greater than zero if condition is becoming true so just add code in else part and check

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution to my problem, instead of removing all items, I assigned an empty array to my dataArray. This works.

```
@IBAction func clearButton(sender: AnyObject) {        
        dataArray = []
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```